# forgot password page in php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forgot-password

I wanted to create a forgot password page. To avoid mailing the user with his details, I decided to display his details in an alert box, although I know that it is much less secure!

So, here's my code in the php file "forgotdetails.php".

```
//Here are my database details, which I can't show.

$conn= mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    // Check connection

    if(!$conn){
        die('Could not connect'.mysql_error() );  
    }

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('users');  

    if(!$db_selected){
        die('wrong'.mysql_error() );
    }



    $post_username = $_POST['email']; // the ajax post username


    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='". $post_username. "'";
    $results= mysql_query($query);
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
    $username=$row['id'];
    $password=$row['pass'];
    if(mysql_num_rows($results)==0)
    {
        echo "pass= " . $password;
        echo "You haven't registered yet! Go to the Home-Page to Register!";
    /*$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$post_username' AND pass='$post_password'";*/

    }
    else
    {   
        echo $password;
    echo "Your Login details are-:"."\nUser ID- ". $username . "\nPassword- ". $password . "\nLogin to your account, to change your password. ";

    }
```

And here's my ajax function (inside the html file) which is getting called as the forgot password button is clicked-:

```
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">


    function ajaxFunction1() {
        var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

        try {
            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            // Internet Explorer Browsers
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    // Something went wrong
                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        // Create a function that will receive data 
        // sent from the server and will update
        // div section in the same page.
            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () 
            { if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) 
                { var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('results'); 
                alert (ajaxRequest.responseText); 
                ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = "<br/><br/><h2><font color='#18E618'>"+ajaxRequest.responseText+"</font></h2>"; } }


        // Now get the value from user and pass it to
        // server script.
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        //var bitsmailid = document.getElementById('bitsmailid').value;

        if ( email== "" ||  email== null ||  email== '') {

            alert("BITS ID Not Filled");

            exit();
        }
        /*if ( bitsmailid== "" ||  bitsmailid== null ||  bitsmailid== '') {

            alert("BITS Mail ID Not Filled");

            exit();
        }*/


        var queryString = "?email=" + email;
        ajaxRequest.open("POST", "forgotdetails.php" +queryString, true);

        ajaxRequest.send(null);
    }

</script>
```

My query is that, the I need to check whether the query returned through SQL in the PHP File ($results) is empty or not and then I need to perform the functions as i have mentioned in my code. I have used mysql_num_rows($results)==0 condition (which I got to know after reading similar posts on Stack Overflow). Although it doesn't seems to evaluate correctly. It evaluates true always, even though there are entries in the database.

I have read all the posts concerning this type of questions on Stack Overflow, and after 12+ hours of testing the code with many different possibilities, still I am still unable to solve my query. I have provided all the details necessary for my query, however If anyone needs anything, I will provide them with you.

I am a newbie into Web Development, so please help me to solve my query. Thank You in advance for your Help!

I am sorry if you feel that this question has already been answered earlier, however I posted this again because those posts sadly couldn't help me. I have read all of them. Sorry!

Comment: Are you saving in `id` column email?

Comment: Are you storing passwords in plain text?

Comment: @RichardA: Yes,within the database I am storing them in plain text.

Comment: That is a TERRIBLE idea. You should NEVER EVER store passwords in plain text. If someone were to hack your database, they can just read all of the passwords.

Comment: @RichardA: I just said that I am a newbie into Web Development. So, i'll do those things later (all security measures). As of now, I am stuck with this issue. Would you suggest any improvement in the code?

Comment: @RichardA - without prepared queries that is a definite possibility of sql injection.

Comment: @AshutoshSaboo - some suggestions would be to use PDO or mysqli instead of mysql, and prepared queries, and then use at least a salted sha1 password hash.  I would also use a email based passport type system to do forgotten passwords, basically generate a onetime use link that will log them in and give it to the user in their email.  Otherwise the way you have above all I need is a users email and I can get their password to your application.

Comment: @AshutoshSaboo That you're a newbie is all fine, everyone has to start somewhere. I too am guilty of using plain text to store passwords in. You should look into hashing and salting using sha1. Also as ArtisiticPhoenix said, you should look into MySQLi or PDO instead of the MySQL extension. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and shouldn't be used because they're unsafe.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix: for sending mails, we need to create an smtp server right? Can you elaborate how to setup sending mails easily?

Comment: @AshutoshSaboo - weather or not you need SMTP depends on your hosting, if your server has a built in mail server then just mail() in php is enough, if you do need to use SMTP, look into a library like PHPmailer or Rmail they will handle it easily.

Comment: @AshutoshSaboo On sending email, look into Swiftmailer or PHPMailer to actually send it. You don't have to create an SMTP server, you can hook into free ones such as gmail (I don't recommend them since they overwrite the From header), a free/paid one such a Mailgun, or if you use a hosting provider, you can just use the libraries I mentioned earlier to send your mail.

Comment: @RichardA: Sorry, I didn't realize about PDO. Actually I have used PDO while registering users, and it is working fine. So now is my password stored in a hashed condition? Because, when I open phpmyadmin, it just shows me password as a simple text. That made me confused. Sorry, didn't realize it earlier.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix: I request your thoughts also on my above comment.

Comment: @AshutoshSaboo In the most simple sense, you can hash a password like so: `sha1($password)`. Salting is recommended too. Just a quick tip: When a user forgot their password, you shouldn't be able to tell them what it is; ALWAYS let them set a new one.

Comment: @AshutoshSaboo - for hashing, you would create a random salt on registration, this is just a string of random numbers and letters, then you add this to the users password and run it through sha1, so pass = sha1( salt + plaintext ), then you save the salt and hash in the db and when they login you take the input password the salt from the account and then hash it the same way this will give you the password to compare to

Comment: @AshutoshSaboo Maybe [this video by Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q) will help you a bit. It's about common practices with passwords and how NOT to do it.

Comment: @AshutoshSaboo - for your actual question above, I would create a passport table, verify the email ( when they put it in the forgotten password form ) generate a random string like a hash and save this in the passport table then email it, then make a page that the email link goes to that accepts that hash you sent and log them in on that page and delete the record from the passport table.  You could also not log them in but give them enough access to change the password.  That way not only do they need to know the email but also have access to it.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix: Actually i learnt how to send a mail to the user, but it requires creating a smtp server right? I sadly don't know how to create a SMTP server. Can you help me out?

Comment: @AshutoshSaboo - you can use gmail's smtp sever if you have an account.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Another option is using Mailgun, but to use that you need to fiddle with DNS a little. Their SMTP service is awesome though. Also, after 10,000 e-mail per month you need to start paying money (a little bit)

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix: How do i use the gmail's smtp server? Is there a guide available? What should be the username that is sending the mail that is to be entered in the PHP script: is it the gmail email address only?

Comment: @AshutoshSaboo To use the Gmail SMTP: You use the following information: http://pastebin.com/EG0fjivJ

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='". $post_username. "'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
 if ($result && (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)) {
     // user exists
     // here you get row
     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 }
```

I know it is without pdo and it is insecure.

Comment: Still, the condition is never evaluating true, and always evaluates to false. I tried it just now.

Comment: Is your db seeded? What is the result of script? Does it end with error or something else?

Comment: Why does id = post username, usernames generally are not ids, looking at the OP  id = username = email.  Perhaps it's correct but it doesn't read well.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix: id is the name of the column. And, $post_username=$_POST['email'] contains the value of the text field entered by the user.

Comment: @JozefDúc: Seeded, what does it mean? No, it doesn't show any error, instead always evaluates to false.

Comment: @AshutoshSaboo - you should name things what they are,

Comment: @AshutoshSaboo seeded = some data in db

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix: Sorry for the confusion! But I had made several PHP scripts already earlier with these column names, so didn't want to change it now.

Comment: @JozefDúc: Yes, there is data inside the db. I have checked it. And moreover I am entering the text fields, such that the condition must evaluate to true, because that data value exists in the database, but still it is evaluating to false.

Comment: @AshutoshSaboo - you have to think what if I look at this a year from now, will I understand then what these are, it's best to use an auto increment "ID" then either have a unique email and a unique login or just use the email for both.  That depends on if other members can see a users login ( email ), and what personal information from a user you are willing to expose to other users.